# PCL compute normals for python

Tags: pcl, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to use PCL's normal estimation class with rospy?

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9507/pcl-compute-normals-for-python/) by [magjossp](https://answers.ros.org/users/319/magjossp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, PCL does not have python bindings yet.

---

Originally posted by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) with karma: 408 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1